# Detectar cuando "aria-checked" de "recaptcha" es true en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, recaptcha

estoy intentando hacer que el *xpath* detecte cuando el valor *aria-checked* es *true* para continuar con el código pero me siempre me da este error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/meganano202/Desktop/MEGA/bot/centriccapital.ltd.pyw", line 136, in <module>
    check_mark = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rc-anchor-container']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/aria-checked='true'")
  File "C:\Python 37 1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python 37 1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python 37 1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python 37 1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='rc-anchor-container']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/aria-checked='true' because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Básicamente quiero que cuando complete el reCaptcha y salga la palomita verde continúe con el código

Esta es la parte del código en la que se ubica:

```
        repassword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[4]/input")
        send_delayed_keys(repassword_elem, e2, 0.2)
        time.sleep(1)
        password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[3]/input")
        send_delayed_keys(password_elem, e2, 0.2)
        check_mark = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/[@aria-checked='true']")
        if check_mark:
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[6]/button").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comprobar si un reCaptcha está resulto primero tienes que localizarlo, para hacer esto normalmente tienes que definir un `iframe` primero.
Así podemos hacer esperar al navegador y una vez encontrado compruebe su valor actual:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # esperamos a que la pagina haya cargado
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "recaptcha")]') # buscamos el iframe del reCaptcha
driver.switch_to.frame(frame) # selecionamos el iframe
captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']") # definimos "captcha" como el objeto final
value = captcha.get_attribute("aria-checked") # comprobamos el valor actual de aria-checked
print("Aria-Checked: {}".format(value)) # Aqui imprimos el valor actual, el resultado seria false
```

Una vez reconocido el *captcha*, vemos que su valor es **false**, entonces tenemos que hacer esperar al navegador hasta que este valor sea ***true***

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui # importamos ui si no está importado

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=120)

confirmar = wait.until(captchaCheck)

if confirmar == True:
    print("Captcha resulto!")
```

Hemos importado `WebDriverWait`, y definido que espere un máximo de *120 segundos* hasta que el captcha devuelva `true`.

La función `wait.until(captchaCheck)` es la responsable de esperar hasta que el captcha se complete, y esta función llama a `captchaCheck`, que la definí como:

```
def captchaCheck(driver):
    try:
        captcha_on = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
        c = captcha_on.get_attribute("aria-checked")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return c == "true"
```

Esta función comprueba el valor de **aria-checked** del captcha, y solo devuelve **`True`**, cuando el atributo del captcha devuelve true, es decir la línea

```
return c == "true"
```

De esta forma, cuando el captcha se complete, la variable `confirmar` que definimos anteriormente, será igual a **True**, y el código imprimirá *Captcha resuelto!*

Comment: vale, vamos a probar, muchas gracias

Comment: funciona perfectamente ( aun que ahora tengo un problema con el código siguiente que no encuentra el botón que tiene que pulsar pero bueno, ya lo intentaré solucionar ) muchas gracias

Comment: ahora me esta dando un error: ```captchaCheck() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given```

Comment: @meganano202 Cambiaste algo del código? Mira haber las diferencias entre el código de antes y el ahora

Comment: si si fue culpa mia, cambie ```captchaCheck(driver)``` por ```captchaCheck()```

Comment: el problema que tengo es el que te dige, no encuentra el botón no entiendo el por q

Comment: @meganano202 Cuál botón no encuentra, el del `captcha`?

Comment: No, mira te explico, necesito que cuando detecte que ha completado el captcha presione el boton de *SIGN UP* de este página [https://centriccapital.ltd/register]